# Insert data into specific columns in SQL Server from C# Datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, ado.net

Suppose my SQL Server table looks like

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5
```

and my datatable looks like

```
Col X | Col Y | Col Z
```

How can I map the values from my datatable to specific columns in the SQL Server table?

The datatable contains a large number of rows so I want to avoid using row by row insert.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'avoid using row by row insert'?

Comment: use a stored procedure with a table valued parameter.

Comment: @LeiYang In this scenario, I can loop the insert command to insert the rows one by one into the sql table. I do not want to use this approach as my datatable contains more than 1000 rows.

Comment: is 1000 rows a big number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stored procedure with a table valued parameter.
Create a user defined table type with the same structure as your c# data table.
Note that the columns of that type must match exactly to the columns of the c# data table, including the order of the columns.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyTableType AS TABLE
(
    ColX int, -- Must be the same data type of ColX in your c# data table
    ColY nvarchar(200), -- Must be the same data type of ColY in your c# data table
    ColZ float -- Must be the same data type of ColZ in your c# data table
)
```

Then you can create the stored procedure, where you will actually do the mapping of columns:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertIntoMyTable
(
    @TableToInsert dbo.MyTableType READONLY -- Table valued parameters must be readonly!
)
AS
    INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    SELECT ColZ, ColX, ColY
    FROM @TableToInsert
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

**SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer Method (DataTable)**

Copies all rows in the supplied DataTable to a destination table specified by the DestinationTableName property of the SqlBulkCopy 
object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This can be used by specifying ColumnMappings from Datatable to SQL Table.